# Difference between strncpy and memcpy?

Tags: c, memcpy, strncpy

How can I access `s[7]` in `s`?

I didn't observe any difference between `strncpy` and `memcpy`. If I want to print the output `s`, along with `s[7]` (like `qwertyA`), what are the changes I have to made in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char s[10] = "qwerty", str[10], str1[10];
    s[7] = 'A';
    printf("%s\n", s);
    strncpy(str, s, 8);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    memcpy(str1, s, 8);
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
qwerty
qwerty
qwerty
```

Comment: Try swapping `memcpy` and `strncpy` in your above code. Then experience the difference.

Comment: Another difference is type checking and the type returned.  Important in other cases, not here.

Answer (score 50):

Others have pointed out your null-termination problems. You need to understand null-termination before you understand the difference between `memcpy` and `strncpy`.

**The main difference is that `memcpy` will copy all N characters you ask for, while `strncpy` will copy up to the first null terminator inclusive, or N characters, whichever is fewer**.

In the event that it copies less than N characters, it will pad the rest out with null characters.

Comment: There's another difference as well, strncpy will fill the rest of the space with 0. e.g. if you do `strncpy(a,b,255);` and a is 10 long, strncpy will copy those 10 characters and fill the remaining 240 characters with 0.

Comment: @nos: I realized that before you did, and edited it in. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Also consider: "No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow)."

Answer (score 8):

You are getting the output `querty` because the index `7` is incorrect (arrays are indexed from 0, not 1). There is a [null-terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) at index `6` to signal the end of the string, and whatever comes after it will have no effect.

Two things you need to fix:

1. Change the `7` in `s[7]` to `6`
2. Add a null-terminator at `s[7]`

The result will be:

```
char s[10] = "qwerty";
s[6] = 'A';
s[7] = 0;
```

[Original not working](http://ideone.com/1Wlvm) and [fixed working](http://ideone.com/WPnsD).

As for the question of [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) versus [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/), the difference is that `strncpy` adds a null-terminator for you. BUT, only if the source string has one before `n`. So `strncpy` is what you want to use here, but be very careful of the big BUT.

Answer (score 4):

Strncpy will copy up to `NULL` even you specified the number of bytes to copy , but memcpy will copy up to specified number of bytes .

printf statement will print  up to NULL , so you will try to print a single charater , it will show ,

```
printf("\t%c %c %c\t",s[7],str[7],str1[7]);
```

## OUTPUT

```
  7              7
```

Answer (score 2):

To make "qwertyA" you need to set `s[6] = 'A'` and `s[7]='\0'`

Strings are indexed from 0, so `s[0] == 'q'`, and they need to be null terminated.

Comment: I should not change s[7] to s[6]. If we set s[6] as 'A' then we will get the desired output..

Comment: @user so you're saying you *don't* want the desired output? O_o

Comment: @user559208: when marcog wrote "change `s[6]` to `s[7]`" I think he actually meant instead of writing s[7], write s[6]. Also, don't forget the null termination of the string (setting `s[7]` to `0` or `'\0'`) because that will help prevent overrun bugs from creeping in.

Comment: You might be right about the confusion there. I've attempted to make the wording clearer.

Comment: @marcog: That's clearer now. Also, sorry for the minor misquote!

Answer (score 2):

When you have:

```
char s[10] = "qwerty";
```

this is what that array contains:

```
s[0]  'q'
s[1]  'w'
s[2]  'e'
s[3]  'r'
s[4]  't'
s[5]  'y'
s[6]   0
s[7]   0
s[8]   0
s[9]   0
```

If you want to add an 'A' to the end of your string, that's at index 6, since array indexes start at 0

```
 s[6] = 'A';
```

Note that when you initialize an array this way, the remaining space is set to 0 (a nul terminator), While not needed in this case, generally be aware that you need to make your strings nul terminated.
e.g.

```
char s[10];
strcpy(s,"qwerty");
s[6] = 'A';
s[7] = 0;
```

In the above example "qwerty" , including its nul terminator is copied to `s`. s[6] overwrites that nul terminator. Since the rest of `s` is not initialized we need to add a nul terminator ourselves with `s[7] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Philip Potter, the main difference is that memcpy will copy all n characters you ask for, while strncpy will copy up to the first null terminator inclusive, or n characters, whichever is less. In the event that strncpy copies less than N characters, it will pad the rest out with null characters.
The below program will answer your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char s[10] = "qwerty",str1[10];
    int i;
    s[7] = 'A';
    memcpy(str1, s, 8);
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if(str1[i]!='\0')
            printf("%c",str1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

o/p:

```
qwertyA
```

Execute the below code and check the difference, you might find it useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[10] = "qwer\0ty", str[10], str1[10];
    s[7] = 'A';
    printf("%s\n",s);
    strncpy(str,s,8);
    printf("%s\n",str);
    memcpy(str1,s,8);
    printf("%s\n",str1);
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        printf("%d=%c,",i,str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        printf("%d=%c,",i,str1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
qwer
qwer
qwer
0=q,1=w,2=e,3=r,4=,5=,6=,7=,
0=q,1=w,2=e,3=r,4=,5=t,6=y,7=A,
```