# Is strncpy() a specialization of memcpy()?

Tags: c++, c, standard-library

Just curious to know (as we use these functions often). I don't see any practical difference between [strncpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) and [memcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/). Isn't it worth to say that effectively,

```
char* strncpy (char *dst, const char *src, size_t size)
{
  return (char*)memcpy(dst, src, size);
}
```

Or am I missing any side effect? There is one similar [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593907/difference-between-strncpy-and-memcpy), but couldn't find an exact answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a difference, see this part of the `strncpy` page you linked to (emphasis mine):

> Copies the first num characters of source to destination. **If the end of the source C string** (which is signaled by a null-character) **is found before num characters have been copied, destination is padded with zeros** until a total of num characters have been written to it.

So if the string to be copied is shorter than the limit, `strncpy` pads with zero while `memcpy` reads beyond the limit (possibly invoking undefined behaviour).

Comment: This has the important effect of ensuring that no memory is accessed beyond the end of the source string. If the string were to be at the end of memory, a `memcpy` could cause an access violation.

Comment: Note also that unlike strlcpy, strncpy writes all of the destination locations with defined values.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same.

**From the C Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E))**

**7.21.2.3 The strcpy function**

**Description**

> 2 The strncpy function copies not more than n characters (characters that follow a null
>   character are not copied) from the array pointed to by s2 to the array pointed to by s1.260) If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>   3 If the array pointed to by s2 is a string that is shorter than n characters, null characters are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by s1, until n characters in all have been written.
>   Returns
>   4 The strncpy function returns the value of s1.

**7.21.2.1 The memcpy function**
**Description**

> 2 The memcpy function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the object pointed to by s1. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>   Returns
>   3 The memcpy function returns the value of s1.

when using `memcpy()` the source and destination buffers can overlap, while in `strncpy()` this must not happen.

According to the C standard, the behavior for overlapping buffers are undefined for both `strncpy()` and `memcpy()`.

***According to the C standard, the real difference between `strncpy()` and `memcpy()` is that if the source string is less then N value, then NULL characters are appended to the remaining N quantity.***

`memcpy()` is more efficient, but less safe, since it doesn't check the source to see if it has N quantity to move to the target buffer.

Comment: +1 for good references. I just missed that null character part

Answer (score 1):

No, `strncpy()` is not a specialization, since it will detect a `'\0'` character during the copy and stop, something `memcpy()` will not do.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to what the others have said, the type of the src and dst pointers does not matter. That is, I can copy a 4 byte integer to 4 consecutive characters of 1 byte like this:

```
int num = 5;
char arr[4];
memcpy(arr, &num, 4);
```

Another difference is that memcpy does not look ofr any characters (such as NULL, by strncpy). It blindly copies num bytes from source to destination.

Edited: Properly formatted the code

Comment: Have you tested your code? Do you mean `memcpy(arr, &num, 4);`?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially make strncpy faster by checking for a \0 and not copying past that point. So memcpy would always copy all the data, but strncpy would often be faster because of the check.

Comment: But one could also argue that it is faster, if you know the strings length, to copy only length byte but without checking each for being the '\0' one.