# What is the difference between memcpy() and strncpy() given the latter can easily be a substitute for the former?

Tags: c, memcpy, strncpy, string.h

What is the significant difference between `memcpy()` and `strncpy()`? I ask this because we can easily alter `strncpy()` to copy any type of data we want, not just characters, simply by casting the first two non-`char*` arguments to `char*` and altering the third argument as a multiple of the size of that non-char type. In the following program, I have successfully used that to copy part of an integer array into other, and it works as good as `memcpy()`.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>


    int main ()
    {
    int arr[2]={20,30},brr[2]={33,44};
    //memcpy(arr,brr,sizeof(int)*1);
    strncpy((char*)arr,(char*)brr,sizeof(int)*1);
    printf("%d,%d",arr[0],arr[1]);

    }
```

Similarly, we can make it work for `float` or other data-type. So what's the significant difference from `memcpy()`?

**PS:** Also, I wonder why `memcpy()` is in `string.h` header file, given nearly all of the library functions there are related to character strings, while `memcpy()` is more generic in nature. Any reason?

Comment: I googled for it,but the only question that resembles it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593907/difference-between-strncpy-and-memcpy ,but it doesn't answer what I intend to ask here.

Comment: memcopy copies unconditionally until it's done however many bytes you wanted. strncpy will copy until it reaches a null (string terminator), or `n` bytes copied. as such you cannot use strncpy on arbitrary binary data, because such data can natually have nulls in it.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509449/is-strncpy-a-specialization-of-memcpy).

Comment: Glad that I got good answers this time instead of a barrage of downvotes like my previous question!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The simple difference is that `memcpy()` can copy data with embedded null characters (aka the string terminator in C-style strings) whereas `strncpy()` will only copy the string to the maximum of either the number of characters given or the position of the first null character (and pad the rest of the strings with 0s).

In other words, they do have two very different use cases.

Comment: Padding with 0 or '0'?I mean NULLs or the character '0'?

Comment: According to this link (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy), it's zeros.

Comment: Character 0 (as in 0x0, not '0') is the null character.  `strncpy()` pads with character 0 (i.e., null characters).

Comment: @nebain You are right about the second part only.Character 0 is NOT the null character,numeric zero is.

Answer (score 5):

Take for example these numbers in your array:

```
 brr[2]={512,44};
```

The least significant byte of the first number `brr[0]` is `0` (`512` is `0x200`) which would causes <sup>1)</sup> `strncpy` to stop copying. `strncpy` does not copy characters that follow a null
character.

<sub>1) To be pedantic (see comments), this holds provided that the implementation has `sizeof (int) > 1` .</sub>

Comment: What if `int` is 16 bit long and stored in big-endian order?

Comment: Same. The null character (although located in a different place) will stop the `strncpy` copy.

Comment: @KerrekSB When a person of your reputation **asks** a question,one is likely to consider it sarcasm.....but then **ouah** is no small-fish either...

Comment: @ouah I am still wondering if your answer and Kerrek's question match.

Comment: @KerrekSB Kerrek,why don't you shed some light into it?

Comment: @Thokchom: What has that to do with anything? I just wanted to clarify that the zero isn't necessarily at the beginning of the byte sequence. Moreover, the zero assumes that bytes have eight bits (but with eigh-bit bytes there will indeed be *some* zero byte somewhere, as ouah rightly points out). All told, this is a somewhat platform-dependent answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB Which part of the answer is platform specific?

Comment: @KerrekSB Shouldn't endianess be a non-issue when we are copying byte by byte?

Comment: @ouah: The claim that there's a zero. If bytes are 10 or 32 bits long, then there wouldn't be one... 32-bit long bytes are not unheard of.

Comment: @KerrekSB but `int` is guaranteed to be at least `16` bits.

Comment: @ouah: Yes, but not two bytes!

Comment: @Thokchom: A byte has `CHAR_BIT` bits.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't want to update it in the question and lengthen it,so can you tell me this --Is the padding done with numeric 0 or the character '0'?

Comment: @KerrekSB Padding in case when the second string is smaller than NUM in `strncpy`.I tested it and it seems it gets padded with NULL terminators till NUM character condition is satisfied.

Comment: @Thokchom: Apologies, I hadn't really intended to engage with the question. I just thought this answer was a little bit iffy. (Without trying in anyway to disparage ouah's usually excellent contributions!)

Comment: @KerrekSB Please Kerrek,last thing,please confirm this, the padding is done with NULL characters eh?Not with the character zero right?

Comment: @KerrekSB A surprising source,the Homeland Security Site,says it gets padded with NULLs..https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi-rules/home/g1/854-BSI.html  BTW What has Homeland Security got to do with these stuff?

Answer (score 0):

When memory block requires to be copied memcpy is useful and data in the for of string strncpy is meaningful because of the natural advantage of '\0' terminated string. Otherwise both perform same pattern of copy after execution.